# Is this a good way to use MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I think this is a decent way to use MediaPlayer for a Button or one time use. Am I right? Is the try block necessary? And what should I be trying to catch here? I'm really having a hard time finding a rock solid way to play a sound once.

```
// Button sound
private void playButtonSound() {
    try{
        final MediaPlayer startPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(
                getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
        startPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                startPlayer.release();
            }
        });
        startPlayer.start();
    } catch(Throwable t){}
}
```

Comment: try to use startPlayer as global variable, check null, and state before using it

Comment: Thanks Thanh. Is the try necessary? Sorry to be so needy, but how do you check state? You mean .isPlaying()?

Comment: I don't think u need a try/catch-block everytime, you must manager state of player, reference here:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Answer (score 0):

I use it like that:

```
  public class PlayaudioActivity extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    stopPlaying();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(PlayaudioActivity.this, R.raw.tosse);
    mp.start();
    }

});


}

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used to do it like this, but I get bug reports. Like this: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: use a boolean flag everywhere you call your stopPlaying() that can be setted to true if you stopped plying, than check if it's false before calling stopPlaying().